# ASM: How to find the type of object contained in ALOAD

Tags: bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation, jvm-bytecode

Let us Consider I have an AbstractInsnNode which is of type ALOAD.
This ALOAD contains an Exception object, while referring the bytecode of the class file. I want to know the desc of the ALOAD using ASM java.
Using LocalVariableNode,(What I did was) I run through the methodNode and found the localvariables name and desc. But Dont know to associate with the corresponding ALOAD.

```
for ( Object a: methodnode.localVariables) {
        LocalVariableNode lvn = (LocalVariableNode)a;
        System.out.println(lvn.desc);
    }


if ((abstractNode.getOpcode() == Constant.ALOAD)) {
           //do Something to check the desc of the ALOAD
            return;
  }
```

Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 1):

An ALOAD instruction includes a numeric argument which tells which local variable it loads. Once we have that, we then look in `methodnode.localVariables` (that you were already printing on screen) to find the correct one.

So one way to go about this to first find out which class represents ALOAD instructions. You can do a google search like "[aload extends abstractinsnnode site:asm.ow2.io](https://www.google.com/search?q=aload+extends+abstractinsnnode+site%3Aasm.ow2.io&btnG=Search&hl=en)" to find the *InsnNode to use. The answer for ALOAD is [VarInsnNode](https://asm.ow2.io/javadoc/org/objectweb/asm/tree/VarInsnNode.html). It surely enough contains a field `int var` which holds the local variable number that it loads. It must match the `int index` field in the `LocalVariableNode` list. However the same index might be reused for different purposes inside the same method, so you also need to verify that your instruction is between the LabelNode instructions indicated by `LabelNode start` and `LabelNode end` instructions in the `LocalVariableNode` as well. Easiest way to do so is to just use the BasicAnalyer as recommended by @Holger in his comment to the [answer by @Antimony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54970931/1356047). So you get the associated Frame object for your VarInsnNode and do `frame.getStack(((VarInsnNode) abstractNode).var)` to get the desc of the variable for the ALOAD instruction.

Comment: `getLocal`, not `getStack`. Mind that `methodnode.localVariables` is only present when the code has been compiled with debug information enabled. If present (and you’re deciding to trust the information), a simple iteration over the instruction nodes would be sufficient. The `BasicAnalyer` is needed if this information is not present or you’re decided not to trust the optional debugging information (as some bytecode instrumentation tools do not care to update it).

Answer (score 0):

Java bytecode is implicitly typed, so there's no direct way to find the types of values in bytecode. You have to do data flow analysis to find where the value was created and get the type that way. If the class has stack maps, then you just need to trace it back to the previous stack map, but it will still require a bunch of work.

Comment: Do we have any reference for the same.

Comment: @SrinivasJayaram see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30363847/2711488) for discussion, how you can get a stack frame for every instruction. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48806265/2711488) takes it up to eleven by trying to predict the actual value, if it originated from a constant.